# Quiero imprimir un PDF en VS con C# sin que se ejecute ADOBE READER que solo imprima directamente

Tags: c#, pdf

Cargo los pdf en un GRID e imprimo los documentos que salgan (Si en la consulta me trae 2 = imprime esos 2 PDFs) el problema es que me genera mucha carga en el servirdor ya que ejecuta adobe para imprimir cada PDF y luego no puedo cerrar el programa me toca cerrar por Administrador de tareas. 
Utilizo este DLL PdfPrintingNet.dll

```
public class imprimirmanifiesto
{
    public void imprimir(string dobleslash)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,

            Verb = "print",

            FileName = "C:\\Users\\bodega\\Documents\\Manifiestos\\" + dobleslash + ".pdf"
        };
        p.Start();

    }
}
```

PARA EL BOTON DE IMPRIMIR

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        r = new imprimirmanifiesto();
        int pos = 0;
        bool a = true;
        while (a == true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataGridView1.Rows[pos].Cells[0].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    a = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    a = true;
                }
                r.imprimir(dataGridView1.Rows[pos].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                pos++;
            }
            catch (Exception q)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

CONSULTA

```
public bool consultar(DataGridView grillita, Decimal factura, String tipo)
    {
        bool resultado = true;
        try
        {
            String consulta;
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
            OracleCommand comando;
            OracleDataReader lector;
            int cuenta = 1;
            int fila = 0;
            grillita.Rows.Clear();
            //con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = Duna02; User Id = DUNA; Password = duna; Unicode = true;";
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source = QWERTY; User Id = DUNA; Password = QWERTY1; Unicode = true;";
            con.Open();
            consulta = "select DISTINCT ULTIMA_IMPORT, MI_ARTIC_FABRICA from CRM_MANIFIESTOS_02 join TIMOVIMIENTODETALLE on CRM_MANIFIESTOS_02.CODIGO = TIMOVIMIENTODETALLE.MV2_ARTIC where TIMOVIMIENTODETALLE.MV2_NUM ='" + factura + "' AND CRM_MANIFIESTOS_02.CODIGO = MV2_ARTIC AND MV2_TIPO ='" + tipo + "' order by CRM_MANIFIESTOS_02.ULTIMA_IMPORT asc";
            comando = new OracleCommand(consulta, con);
            lector = comando.ExecuteReader();
            while (lector.Read())
            {
                grillita.Rows.Add();
                grillita.Rows[fila].Cells[2].Value = lector.GetDecimal(0);
                grillita.Rows[fila].Cells[1].Value = "Manifiesto " + lector.GetDecimal(0) + "-" + lector.GetString(1);
                grillita.Rows[fila].Cells[0].Value = cuenta;
                fila++;
                cuenta++;
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception abc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Verifique número de importación y seleccione un tipo");
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le hice algunas modificaciones a tu codigo.
Primero que nada necesitas saber cual ejecutable correr para que adobe se ejecute e imprima el archivo que desees y luego pasarle ese mismo archivo entre sus parametros, la ruta de lo primero puede variar por tanto solo adaptalo a tus condiciones

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Llamo el metodo estaticamente para imprimir el pdf que paso por parametro
        imprimirmanifiesto.imprimir(@"D:\Cursos\Neural_Networks_Using_C_Sharp_Succinctly.pdf");
    }
}

public class imprimirmanifiesto
{
    //Constante que representa la ubicación del ejecutable de AdobeReader en este caso es la carpeta
    public const string RUTA_ADOBE = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader";
    //Hice la función estatica para no instanciarla, puedes removerlo y dejarlo a tu gusto
    public static void imprimir(string archivo)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            //Le paso el parametro /p para imprimir y posteriormente la ruta del archivo que va a imprimir
            Arguments = string.Format("/p \"{0}\"", archivo),
            //Nombre del ejecutable de Adobe Reader
            FileName = "AcroRd32.exe"
        };
        p.Start();
    }
}
```

Bueno nada espero que te funcione ;P

Comment: Muchas gracias, yo debo de imprimir mas de un documento PDF en todos al dar click sobre el boton imprimir hace lo siguiente.

Comment: Los archivos estan en un mismo directorio o en rutas diferentes???

Comment: En el mismo directorio
C:\\Users\\bodega\\Documents\\Manifiestos\
entonces hago lo siguiente y es donde sale el error
http://oi65.tinypic.com/263bfuw.jpg

Comment: Mira ya hice que imprimiera mas de un archivo dandole una ruta, pero esta el inconveniente de que no se cierra solo el adobe, en tu version se cierra luego de imprimir o lo tienes que hacer manualmente??

Comment: Manualmente y ademas el programa en C# se congela o simplemente se cierra pero el proceso queda en el background

Comment: Mira el problema es que cuando con comandos abres adobe reader para imprimir luego de hacer esa operación el deja una instancia abierta y hasta que no se cierre esta no se ejecutara la proxima impresión, puedes abrirlas todas simultaneamente y poner un timer para que pasado x tiempo se cierrren todos los procesos asociados a adobe reader, pero eso no seria lo mejor ya que no sabrias cuanto tardaria cada uno en imprimirse

Comment: Estoy muy agradecido por la ayuda, cual piensa que puede ser la solucion para imprimir los PDF casi siempre debo imprimir mas de un documento, la consulta me trae 3 o hasta 10, los visualizo en el GRID y los imprimo. pero debo abrir el administrador de tareas para matar el proceso luego de terminar de imprimir y asi volver a repetir el proceso.

Comment: ves alguna solucion en otro lenguaje?

Comment: mira si lo ke te preocupa es matar el proceso cuando acabes puedes poner un tiempo medio y usar el Process para matarlos todos, con Timer t = new Timer(); t.Interval = 100;
Stopwatch clock = new Stopwatch();
clock.Start();
t.Tick += (o, s) =>
{
 clock.Stop();
 if(clock.Elapsed.TotalMinutes > 2)
 {
  foreach(Process ar in Process.GetProcessesByName("AcroRd32"))
  {
   ar.Kill();
  }
  t.Stop();
 }
 clock.Start();
};
t.Start();

Comment: Con lo anterior garantizas ke pasado mas de 2 minutos se maten todos esos procesos automaticamente

Comment: Creo que lo mejor seria no trabajar con ADOBE, imprimir directamente o usar otro programa

Comment: Si va ser lo mejor

Comment: Mira agregue el codigo de la consulta

Comment: @DarielRamosDíazdeVillegas se podría utilizar el mismo código(obviamente cambiando el nombre del ejecutable) para un lector de PDF diferente?

Comment: Siempre que le pases la ruta de ese ejecutable, SIIII